# multistore customer login and add to cart fails

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, login

We have following situation on Magento 1.9.2.2 installation (ultimo theme) with multistore setup as websites in subfolders, e.g. domain.com/en-ca, etc..

Add to cart works when on the default website (domain.com) but not when using a website in the subfolder, e.g. domain.com/en-ca/

-Add to cart works when a user is logged in. 
-Same problem on staging and live domain (same hosting environment)
-Share customer accounts set to global.

No erros are reported in system log. Cookie setting as follows:

- Cookie Lifetime: 86400
- Cookie Path: /
- Cookie domain: staging.domain.com
- Http only: yes  Cookie restriction mode: No

Frontend session cookies are carried over when trying to add something to the cart, but cart remains empty. If leaving Cookie Path and Cookie domain field empty: Cookie is set in path /en-ca when checking browser dev tools.

Form-key validation should not cause this because it works on default website?
I suspect it is due to the multi-store setup as it works on default site. However, all else on multistore seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it. The exception.log file gave the answer.

The error was: 'Zend_Cache_Exception' with message 'cache_dir "tmp/" must be a directory' in /xxx/xxx/magento_staging/lib/Zend/Cache.php:209

Found the answer to this issue here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031456/message-cache-dir-must-be-a-directory

Then modified file.php in lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/  on line 98 from

```
 protected $_options = array(
        'cache_dir' => '/tmp',
```

to

```
 protected $_options = array(
        'cache_dir' => '/your/path/magento_staging/tmp',
```